# Increasing volume/power levels on USB Audio device (64 bit Windows 7)

Tags: windows-7, usb, audio, 64-bit, usb-audio

I have a USB audio device (Buddy USB 6G) that was cheap and worked great- until I updated windows recently.  Now it seems the power/volume reaches its max at about 50% volume, and any further increase in the volume control does nothing.

The headphones I'm using are fine, they are very loud on my phone.  This problem emerged after a windows update.

I suspect the driver needs to be updated, but the company hasn't issued a new one. They seem to have stopped supporting the device.

Does anyone have any suggestions or know of a registry fix? I really would like this to work because my built in mic jack is broken.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uninstall the driver-software for it (control panel>programs and features) and reboot, then reinstall. If the driver-software does not show in programs list then use device manager to uninstall>reboot.

Comment: Thanks, this did it!  Can you please explain why this solution works? It seems mysterious to me.

Comment: Evidently the driver became corrupt, reinstalling it removes the corruption, this has been a solution for driver problems in windows for a long time.